# How to see the output of socket.html?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i am newbie to node.js.
I was trying to implement [danielnill example](http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/) tutorial

**server.js**

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            break;
        case 'socket.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, "utf8");
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
            break;
    }
    response.end();
});

server.listen(8001);

io.listen(server);
```

**socket.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect();
    </script>
    <div>This is our socket.html file</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

when ever i am trying run this `http://localhost:8001/socket.html` url from browser. Its goes to default case instead going to 'socket.html' case.

Pls help me to execute 'socket.html' case in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with what you have posted:

1. The `path` variable equals `/socket.html` when the URL `http://localhost:8001/socket.html` is requested, not `socket.html`;  you need to update the case statement accordingly.
2. The `fs.readFile` callback will not be able to write the response to back to the client (browser), as `response.end();` will have already been called; you need to move `response.end()` into each of the `case` statements.

Here is the updated code:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            response.end();
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, "utf8");
                }
                response.end();
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
            response.end();
            break;
    }
});

server.listen(8001);

io.listen(server);
```