# Node Js Fevicon.ico issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to the NodeJs and started doing this http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/ tutorial for node js but when i hit the url it is automatically requesting the 'fevico.ico' and also it is not showing the required html page content. I tried short circuiting the 'fevico.ico' request but it does not work and also i dont have any tools to debug server side js code thats why its getting very frustrated to solve this issue below is my code and screen shot of the console log screen.

My server.js file code

```
  var http=require("http");
  var url=require('url');
  var fs=require('fs');

  var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
console.log('Connection');
var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
console.log(path);
switch(path)
{
    case '/':
        response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        response.write('heloo world');
        break;
    case '/socket.html':
        fs.readFile(__dirname+path,function(error,data){
        console.log(data.toString());
            if(error!=null)
            {
                response.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
                response.write('oops this does not exist - 404');
            }
            else
            {
                response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
                response.write(data,"utf8");
            }
        });
        break;
    case '/favicon.ico':
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
        console.log('favicon requested');
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
response.end();
});
server.listen(8001);
```

and my console screen looks like

[image]

so I know it is getting the file content for the socket.html file but it does not displaying on the browser from response.write and again sending the automated request to the `fevico.ico`.Is there something I am doing wrong ? Any help or directions would be great.

Comment: There is a bug in his tutorial:  see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23428410/142162).

Comment: The fs.readFile is async. Your response.end is called before.